# java.lang.NullPointerException in Server

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

hello I'm writing a code fore a chat server using Vectors and threads,
but i get this error and i don't know why?

the error occurs in : ClientList.add(new Personnel(nekname,client) );

this is my code:

```
public class chatServer { 

  private static ServerSocket serverSocket; 
  private static final int PORT = 5002; 

  public static Vector<Personnel> ClientList;

  public static void main(String[ ] args) throws IOException 
  { 
    try { 
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
      ClientList = new Vector<Personnel>();
    } 
    catch (IOException ioEx) { 
      System.out.println("\nUnable to set up port!"); 
      System.exit(1);
      } 
    do {
      Socket client = serverSocket.accept(); 
      System.out.println("\nNew client accepted.\n"); 
      ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler(client); 
      handler.start();
    }while (true); 
  } 
} 
class ClientHandler extends Thread 
{ 
  private Socket client; 
  private Scanner input; 
  private PrintWriter output;

  public static Vector<Personnel> ClientList;

  public ClientHandler(Socket socket) { 
    client = socket; 
    try { 
      input = new Scanner(client.getInputStream()); 
      output = new PrintWriter( client.getOutputStream(),true); 
    } 
    catch(IOException ioEx) { 
      ioEx.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
  } 

  public void run() { 
    String received; 
    String nekname;

    nekname = input.nextLine();

    ClientList.add(new Personnel(nekname,client) );

    try{
      for(Personnel person:ClientList){
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(person.getLink().getOutputStream(),true); 
      out.println(nekname + " has entered the chatroom");
      }
    }
   catch(IOException ioEx) { 
      ioEx.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    do {
      received = input.nextLine(); 
      try{
      for(Personnel person:ClientList){
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( person.getLink().getOutputStream(),true); 
      out.println(nekname + ": " + received);
      }
      }
      catch(IOException ioEx) { 
      ioEx.printStackTrace(); 
    } 

    }while (!received.equals("Bye") || !received.equals("bye"));

    try { if (client!=null) {
      for(Personnel person:ClientList){
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( person.getLink().getOutputStream(),true); 
      out.println(nekname + " has left the chatroom");
      }
      System.out.println( "Closing down connection...");
      client.close(); } 
    } 
    catch(IOException ioEx) { 
      System.out.println("Unable to disconnect!");
    } 
  } 
}

 class Personnel{
    private String nickname;
    private Socket link;

    public Personnel(String name,Socket l){
      nickname = name;
      link = l;
    }

    public String getName(){
      return nickname;
    }

     public Socket getLink(){
      return link;
    }
 }
```

any help?

Comment: Please add the error message / exception that you're getting.

Comment: What server? Version? Add the stacktrace.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code was easy to debug by inspection _this time_, but for future posts please remember to post the _complete_ stack trace (format as for code) and indicate the line in your code pointed to by the exception.  If the exception is in library code, find the point closest to the top of the stack that _is_ in your code and identify _that_ line.  Include any other information that _you_ would ask for is somebody brought the problem to you.

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" the answer that best helps you (click the check mark next to the answer).

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `ClientList` in your `ClientHandler` class as well.

```
public static Vector<Personnel> ClientList
                                = new Vector<Personnel>(); // initialization MISSING!
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize your `ClientList` in `ClientHandler` class.

```
 public static Vector<Personnel> ClientList;
```

Answer (score 2):

Reason for exception is that you declared `ClientList` but never `initialized` it in `ClientHandler` class.